# Mail Server Spam Security Issue

Tags: php, security, web, spam

I'm getting spam emails from my web form every week. I have tried to make some changes in my query, but that hasn't helped. I am sharing my query below, including the headers.

Can someone help me find where the problem is?

```
<?php
    $submitted_email = '';
    if (isset($_SESSION['form'][$mail_from_email])) {
        $submitted_email = $_SESSION['form'][$mail_from_email];
    }

    if (check_email($submitted_email) && $send_from_users_email === false) {
        $from = $reply_to = $_SESSION['form'][$mail_from_name].' <'.$submitted_email.'>';
    } else {
        $from = '<'.$email.'>';
        $reply_to = check_email($submitted_email) ? '<'.$submitted_email.'>' : $from;
    }

    $subject = '';
    if (isset($_SESSION['form'][$mail_subject])) {
        $subject = $_SESSION['form'][$mail_subject];
    }

    //email headers
    if ($windows_server === true) {
        $headers  = "From: test.co.uk\r\n" .
        "Reply-to: test.co.uk\r\n" .
        "Return-Path: test.co.uk\r\n".
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; " .
        "boundary=$mixed_mime_boundary";
    } else {
        $headers  = "From: $from\n" .
        "Reply-to: $reply_to\n" .
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; " .
        "boundary=$mixed_mime_boundary";
    } else {
        $headers  = "From: $from\n" .
        "Reply-to: $reply_to\n" .
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; " .
        "boundary=$mixed_mime_boundary";
    }



    ////////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCT HTML CONTENT //
    ////////////////////////////

    //Construct HTML email content, looping through each form element

    //Note: When you get to a file attachment you need to use $_FILES['form_element']['name']
    //This will just output the name of the file. The files will actually be attached at the end of the message.

    //Set a variable for the message content
    $html_content = "<html>\n<head>\n<title>" .
    safe_escape_string($subject) .
    "</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p>\n";

    ////////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCT TEXT CONTENT //
    ////////////////////////////

    //construct a plain text version of the email.
    $text_content = '';

    //build a message from the reply for both HTML and text in one loop.
    foreach ($form_fields as $field => $label) {
        $html_content .= '<b>' . safe_escape_string($label) . '</b> ';
        $text_content .= "$label ";
        if (isset($_FILES[$field])) {
            $string = (isset($_FILES[$field]['name'])) ? $_FILES[$field]['name'] : '';
        } else {
            $string = (isset($_SESSION['form'][$field])) ? $_SESSION['form'][$field] : '';
        }
        $html_content .= nl2br(safe_escape_string($string)) . "<br /><br />\n";
        $text_content .= "$string\n\n";
    }

    //close the HTML content.
    $html_content .= "</p>\n</body>\n</html>";

    /////////////////////////////
    // CONSTRUCT EMAIL MESSAGE //
    /////////////////////////////

    //Now we combine both HTML and plain text version of the email into one.
    //Creating the message body which contains a Plain text version and an HTML version,
    //users email client will decide which version to display
    $message = "\r\n--$mixed_mime_boundary\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$alt_mime_boundary\r\n\r\n" .
    "--$alt_mime_boundary\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\r\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable\r\n\r\n" .
    "$text_content\r\n\r\n" .
    "--$alt_mime_boundary\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable\r\n\r\n" .
    "$html_content\r\n\r\n" .
    "--$alt_mime_boundary--\r\n\r\n" .
    "\r\n\r\n--$mixed_mime_boundary";


    //////////////////////
    // FILE ATTACHMENTS //
    //////////////////////

    //loop through the $_FILES global array and add each attachment to the form.
    if (isset($_FILES)) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $attachment) {
            $filename = $attachment['name'];

            //if the file has been uploaded
            if ($attachment['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file($attachment['tmp_name'])) {
                $file = fopen($attachment['tmp_name'],'rb');
                $data = fread($file,filesize($attachment['tmp_name']));
                fclose($file);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

                $message .= "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\"" .
                "\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"" .
                "\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n$data\r\n\r\n--$mixed_mime_boundary";
            } else if ($attachment['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                //try to provide a useful error message determined from the error code.
                switch ($attachment['error']) {
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                        $error = "File $filename exceeds the " . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . 'B limit for the server.';
                        break;
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                        $error = "Only part of the file $filename could be uploaded, please try again.";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $error = "There has been an error attaching the file $filename, please try again.";
                }
                redirect($return_url, $error);
            }
        }
    }


    //finish off message
    $message .= '--';

    //for windows users.
    if ($windows_server === true) {
        ini_set('sendmail_from', $email);
    }

    //if the mail sending works
    if (@mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        //set the success message
        $notice = $message_success;
        unset($_SESSION['form']);
    } else {
        $notice = "I'm sorry, there seems to have been an error trying to send your email. Please try again.";
    }

    //redirect to the form
    redirect($return_url, $notice);
}

?>
```

Comment: Spamming bots must have indexed your form. Are you using any kind of CAPTCHA or reCAPTCHA at your form?

Comment: I am not using captcha for my form. I am very new to the coding and unsure how to deal with this.

Regards

Comment: You need to add it to your form. Follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/. It is not a coding issue what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have added reCAPTCHA in my form. Will check now if this will resolve the issue.